# Need pattern which allows alphanumeric with 3 special character - . whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate a address field which can contain alphanumeric characters with `-`, `.` and whitespace. The first character should not be `-` or `.`. Repeated special characters (`--`  `-.` `..`) are also not allowed. I have tried this pattern but no use

```
Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9-\\.\\s]*$")
```

Kindly please provide me the pattern which matches strings like this `A-133 Rock Appt.`

Comment: Please copy/paste actual code (and put four spaces before it in the editor here)

Answer (score 3):

```
^\w++(?:[.\s-](?![.\s-])|\w++)*$
```

does this (double the backslashes for use in a Java string).

**Explanation:**

```
^           # Start of string
\w++        # Match one or more alnum characters, possessively
(?:         # Match either
 [.\s-]     #  a single "special" character
 (?![.\s-]) #  aserting that it's really single
|           # or
 \w++       # one or more alnum characters, possessively
)*          # zero or more times
$           # End of string
```

The possessive quantifiers (`++`) help the regex to fail faster if the string doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 ist correct, if underscore is also allowed. The Regexp of Answer 1 also accepts:

```
_A-133 Rock Appt.
```

If underscore is not allowed replace `\w` with `[a-z0-9A-Z]`